# show map with current user location with RouteMe code

Tags: ios, userlocation, route-me

I want to display in my project a map with the current user location.

I want to use RouteMe code and not google map.
I searched examples for this but i didn't find.

Does anyone know how can i do it???

Thanks.

Comment: You should indicate more tags and more info in your question: which language, which framework, …?

Answer (score 2):

How did you embed the RMMapView? Programatically or using a NIB? If you're using a NIB I cann't help you as I got stucked there as RMMapView wouldn't get initialized properlly.

If you embed it programatically, just use CoreLocation to grab your current location and use the method "moveToLatLon" of the RMMapView to go to the current location.

Is that what you are looking for?